# Email body ignores HTML markup

Tags: webforms

Am using webforms and under the email handler, I have the following as email body:

```
<p>Submitted on [webform_submission:created]</p>

<p>Submitted values are:</p>
<br />
<strong>Name:</strong>&nbsp;[webform_submission:values:name]<br />
<br />
<strong>Surname:</strong> [webform_submission:values:surname]<br />
<br />
<strong>Email:</strong> [webform_submission:values:email]<br />
<br />
<strong>Mobile:</strong> [webform_submission:values:mobile]<br />
<br />
<strong>Date of Birth:</strong> [webform_submission:values:date_of_birth]&nbsp;<br />
<br />
<strong>Country:</strong> [webform_submission:values:country]<br />
<br />
<strong>Region:</strong> [webform_submission:values:region]<br />
<br />
<strong>Enquiry:</strong> [webform_submission:values:enquiry]<br />
<br />
<strong>Message:</strong> [webform_submission:values:message]<br />
&nbsp;
```

Under the advanced section, I clicked the option to send email as HTML. However, the following is what I see in the email body:

`Submitted on Wed, 04/22/2020 - 09:21 Submitted values are: *Name:* MyName *Surname:* MySurname *Email:* myexample@example.com [1] *Mobile:* 0212212254 [2] *Date of Birth:* Wed, 12/12/1990 - 00:00  *Country:* AO *Region:* GP-P` *Enquiry:* [webform_submission:values:enquiry] *Message:* hvnbvnm   [1] mailto:myexample@example.com [2] tel:0212212254

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see any HTML in your configuration. Are there any `<div></div>` or `<p></p>` tags in there?

Comment: I copied and pasted everything from the editor, not the source. But I will edit the question using the source instead if that helps to find the answer

Comment: Which module are you using for sending your Email? It looks like your mailsystem module converts the email for you